# mongodb text search partial match

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, live, mongoose-schema

Hii All I want to perform like query with two different search terms with two different fields .But none of my code works .Please help .
I want to perform below sql query in mongodb or mongoose:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE title LIKE '%$title%' OR location LIKE '%$location%';
```

I have tried with the codes given below but none of these working at all:

```
         ***1. First Code***
var searchString1 = req.body.location;
  var searchString2 = req.body.title;

Customer.find({$or:[{ "location": /searchString1/ },{ "title": /searchString2/ }]}).exec(function(err,jobs){}

         ***2. Second Code***
Customer.find({"$or":[
                {"title":new RegExp(req.body.title,'i')},
                {"location":new RegExp(req.body.location,'i')}
            ]}).exec(function(err,jobs){}
```

Please Help

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. "not working" is not a problem statement. You are supposed to describe how actual result differ  from the expected one, and provide an mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, which in your case should contain couple of documents in the `Customer` collection and the terms you are using to find them. Also, there is a missing opening `[` in the first query.

Comment: I have tried after adding missing opening [ in the first query but still not giving any results

Comment: mind updating question with the correct query?

Comment: Query Updated.Please give the solution

Comment: Dear Bipin, please re-read my first comment. All of it. Adding a bracket doesn't make it reproducible.